# Can not find a (Map) Key deserializer for type

Tags: jackson

I am getting exception while read like 
oMapper.readValue(jsonString, new MyData().getClass());

org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: 
Can not find a (Map) Key deserializer for type.

How to fix it?

Comment: Quick note on usage: can do that simpler with `obMapper.readValue(jsonString, MyData.class)`

Answer (score 0):

What does `MyData` look like? It appears to have a property with type `Map`, which has a custom key type?